# Windows 10 PC not using all 16 GB

Tags: windows-10, memory

I was looking into the specs of my computer and I noticed that Windows was only recognizing 8 GB of RAM even though I have 16 GB installed. I tried putting one stick at a time and each showed 8 GB active so they are not defective. I am wondering how to get my Windows 10 PC (64-bit) to access all 16 GB.

Comment: Are you putting them in the correct slots in your mainboard? Sometimes they need to be in slot 1+3, not 1+2. So what RAM and Mainboard are you using? What about your CPU?

Comment: I’m using a GIGABYTE b450 Aorus pro WiFi, and Corsair Vengeance LPX 16GB. I’m not sure about my CPU.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should take a look in the manual from the mainboard to confirm this

> According to your manual, from left to right the slots are 4231. Your manual specifically says to put the RAM in slots "1 & 2" or "3 & 4", which is "-1-1" or "1-1-" (- is a free slot, 1 is a RAM stick)
>
> For optimum performance, when enabling Dual Channel mode with two memory modules, we recommend that you install them in the DDR4_1 and DDR4_2 sockets.

[Taken from Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/buildapc/comments/aiczpc/b450_aorus_pro_wifi_ram_install_question/)

Comment: Thanks I’ll let you know if this works!

Comment: It worked when I used slots 2 and 4. Anyways, thanks for your help.

Comment: Slots 2&4 when counting from left to right or when using the numbering mentioned in the post? Anyway, you can give this post an upvote if it helped you :)